# Push objects (same keys names) in array using angular.forEach ()

Tags: angularjs

How I push objects with same key name into an array using `angular.forEach()` function ?

for example, I declare an empty array i.e. `$scope.arr = []` and an empty object i.e. `$scope.obj = {}`

Now using `angular.forEach()` and `push()` function, how can I get the following result :

*$scope.arr = `[{msg: ''}, {msg: 'please, enter no.'}, {msg: ''}]`*

**my JS code**

```
$scope.arr = []
$scope.obj = {}
       angular.forEach(['12', 'Please, enter no.', '43'], function (value, index) {
           if (isNaN (value)) {
                $scope.obj['msg'] = 'Please, enter no.';
                $scope.arr.push($scope.obj);
           }
           else {
                $scope.obj['msg'] = '';
                $scope.arr.push($scope.obj);
           }
       });
```

**Current wrong output :** `$scope.arr = [{msg: 'please, enter no.'}, {msg: 'please, enter no.'}, {msg: 'please, enter no.'}]`

**Expected Output :** `$scope.arr = [{msg: ''}, {msg: 'please, enter no.'}, {msg: ''}]`

I knew why I got wrong output because all the `msg` keys are updated with last value of array, but I could not find the remedy for this.

Please, help me.....

Answer (score 1):

Why create a `$scope` object? As you have found this will just keep adding the same object reference to your array. How about:

```
angular.forEach(['12', '43', 'Please, enter no.'], function (value, index) {
    if (isNaN (value)) {
        $scope.arr.push({ msg: 'Please, enter no.' });
    }
    else {
        $scope.arr.push({ msg: '' });
    }
});
```

Comment: Lex : thanks yaar (means friend in Indian language).. nice trick. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I got reason about wrong output of above code is that I wrongly declared `$scope.obj = {}` outside the angular.forEach () function but it should be declared inside it. By doing so, everytime new object will created in each iteration.

**Corrected JS Code :**

```
$scope.arr = []
angular.forEach(['12', 'Please, enter no.', '43'], function (value, index) {
           $scope.obj = {}
           if (isNaN (value)) {
                $scope.obj['msg'] = 'Please, enter no.';
                $scope.arr.push($scope.obj);
           }
           else {
                $scope.obj['msg'] = '';
                $scope.arr.push($scope.obj);
           }
       });
```

Comment: Then why are you creating it as a scope object at all? You are probably better of just omitting that part instead as it provides no additional functionality but registers the object to the scope during each iteration.